# How to Update one column in a database table using two array values in Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, sql-update

Here i have combined two arrays to update a column called Age in an Employee table. But unfortunately the values of the column is not getting updated.

Bellow `$names[]` and `$ages[]` are the two arrays.

```
foreach (array_combine($names, $ages) as $e => $f) 
{
$sql = "UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= '" . $e . "' WHERE `A`= '" . $f . "'";
$query= mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Instead if i give print command

```
 echo $sql  // its printing the correct command, like

UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= '41' WHERE `A`= '" . Samuel . "'
UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= '46' WHERE `A`= '" . Sonal . "'
```

I know there is a problem with the arrays into the update sql query but i don't know how to rectify it.

Comment: Have you tried `print_r(array_combine($names,$ages));`? What does it print out?

Comment: I think you need to retype query like `"UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= '" . $f . "' WHERE `A`= '" . $e . "'"`

Comment: Then is it right in `Age` came  'Samuel' and `name` get  `41`.??

Comment: does `A` refers to name .. ?

Comment: You can use following code to track exact error..

    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query can be written this way...

```
$sql = "
UPDATE Employee SET Age= $e WHERE A= '$f';
";
```

Also, (and obviously), don't store someone's age. Store their DOB. And note that the mysql_ extension is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to flip `$e` and `$f` in you `foreach()` loop `$sql`-

```
foreach (array_combine($names, $ages) as $e => $f){
   $sql = "UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= '" . $f . "' WHERE `A`= '" . $e . "'";
   $query= mysql_query($sql);
}
```

This will give you

```
UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= '41' WHERE `A`= 'Samuel'
UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= '46' WHERE `A`= 'Sonal'
```

instead of

```
UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= 'Samuel' WHERE `A`= '41'
UPDATE `Employee` SET `Age`= 'Sonal' WHERE `A`= '46'
```

Comment: Have you tried using `or die(mysql_error())` -  `$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`, or have you tried copying the query into phpMyAdmin

Comment: If its working phpMyAdmin your probably not connected to mysql properly?